# MySQL help - What employees have worked more than 50 hours on a single assignment? Use a subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables, assignment and employee. They are linked through EmployeeNumber and HoursWorked is an attribute stored in assignment. I have tried this and I get an error saying the subquery returns more than 1 row. What am I doing wrong:

```
SELECT e.FirstName, e.LastName
FROM employee e
WHERE (
    SELECT a.HoursWorked
    FROM assignment a
    WHERE a.HoursWorked > 50);
```

Comment: You need to select where the `employeenumber` in the outer query matches the `employeenumber` in the subquery. I.E. select `employeenumber` in your subquery, not `hoursworked`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to do something like this:

```
SELECT e.FirstName, e.LastName
FROM employee
JOIN assignment on employee.EmployeeNumber = assignment.EmployeeNumber
WHERE assignment.HoursWorked > 50;
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT e.FirstName, e.LastName
FROM employee e
WHERE e.EmployeeNumber IN (
    SELECT EmployeeNumber
    FROM assignment a
    WHERE a.HoursWorked > 50);`

Comment: Would work fine in MySQL 4.0+, although some people prefer JOINs.  Interestingly, some SQL implementations, such as Oracle, have an implied LIMIT 1000 in *any* nested SELECT statement, and simply won't tell you that they're not actually selecting all values available...